# Moving from single user desktop applications to multiuser development

Tags: c#, multi-user

I'm trying to bootstrap a micro ISV on my nights and weekends. I have an application at a very early stage of development. It is written in C# and consists mainly of a collection of classes representing the problem domain. At this point there's no UI or data persistence. (I haven't even settled on the .NET platform. Its early enough that I could change to Java or native executables)

My goal for this application is that it will be a hybrid single user/ occasionally connected multiuser application. The single user part will use an embedded database for local storage. This is a development model I'm familiar with.

The multiuser part is where I have no prior experience. I know each user will need two things:

- IP based communication to a remote server on the public internet
- User authentication and remote data storage

I have an idea of what services I want this server to provide (information lookup and user to user transactions) but beyond that I'm out of my element. The server will need to be hosted by a third party since I don't have resources to run my own server. Keeping in mind that I will be the sole developer for this project for the foreseeable future:

1. Which technologies would be the simplest way to implement the two things mentioned above? Direct access to the datastore/database or is it better to isolate it? Should I implement a webservice? If so, SOAP or REST?
2. What other things do I need to consider when moving to a multiuser application?
   I know security is a greater concern in a multiuser application. Especially when your dealing with any kind of banking information(which I will). Performance can be an issue when dealing with a remote connection and large numbers of users. Anything else I'm overlooking?

Comment: sql-azure? http://www.microsoft.com/windowsazure/sqlazure/

Answer (score 2):

Regarding moving to a multiuser application, centralising your data is the first step of course, and the simplest way to achieve it is often to use a cloud-based database, such as Amazon SimpleDB or MS Azure.  You typically get an access key and a long 'secret' for authentication.

If your data isn't highly relational, you might want to consider Amazon SimpleDB.  There are SDKs for most languages, which allow simple code to store/retrieve data in your SimpleDB database using a key and secret, anywhere in the world.  You pay for the service based on your data storage and volume of traffic, so it has a very low barrier of entry, especially during development.  It will also scale from a tiny home application up to something of the size of amazon.com.

If you do choose to implement your own database server, you should remember two key things:

1. Ensure no session state exists, i.e. the client makes a call to your web service, some action occurs, and the server forgets about that client (apart from any changed data in the database of course).  Similarly the client should not be holding any data locally that could change as a result of interaction from another user.  Cache locally only data you know won't change (or that you don't care if it changes).
2. For a web service, each call will typically be handled on its own thread, and so you need to ensure that access to the database from multiple threads is safe.  If you use the standard .NET or Java ways of talking to a SQL database, this should be handled for you.  However, if you implement your own data storage, it would be something you'd need to worry about.

Regarding the question of REST/SOAP etc., a key consideration should be what kinds of platforms/devices you want to use to connect to the database server.  For example if you were implementing your server in .NET you might consider WCF for implementing your web services.  However that might introduce difficulties if you later want to use non-.NET clients.  SOAP is a mature technology for web services, but quite onerous to implement, and libraries to wrap up the handling of SOAP calls may not necessarily be available for a given client platform.  REST is simple to implement (trivially easy if you use ASP.NET MVC on your server), accessible by any client that can handle HTTP POST/GET without the need for libraries, and easy to test, so REST would be my technology of choice.

Answer (score 1):

If you are sticking with .net (my personal preference), I would expose data access calls via WCF.  WCF configuration is really flexible and pretty easy to pick up and you'll want to hide your DB behind a service layer.

Answer (score 0):

1.Direct access to db is the simplest, and the worst. Just think about how you'd auth the db access... I would just write a remote-able API with serializable parameters, and worry about which methods to connect later (web services, IIOP, whatever) - the communication details are all wrapped and hidden anyway.

2.none